# why setting an adapter to a listView doesn't show the list content?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

I try to fill a listView with the following code:

```
private void getPhoneComments(View rootView) {
    String phoneNumber = ((EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.phone_editText)).getText().toString();
    Phone phone = phoneDal.getItem(phoneNumber);
    if (phone != null) {
        List<String> comments = commentDal.getAllItems(phone.id);
        ListView lv = ((ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.comments_list));
        // This is the array adapter, it takes the context of the activity as a
        // first parameter, the type of list view as a second parameter and your
        // array as a third parameter.
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                comments);

        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

but the list still isn't displayed to the screen.

1) When do I need to add `invalidate data`
or what else I need to change in order to code to work?

2) how can i disply an option popup when there was a long push on each list item?

Edit:

`phone != null`

`comments != empty`

lv is set OK:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_detail, container, false);
    setCommentsVisibility(rootView, false);

    lv = ((ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.comments_list));
```

[image]

Comment: maybe comments is empty, or phone is null, or the ListView is not attached to the current view hierarchy ?

Comment: post code which retrieves rootView

Comment: Can you post the layout file for your fragment?

Comment: is onCreateView returning rootView?